# How to find the sum: $ \sum_{i = 0}^n i^{1/5} $

Tags: summation, euler-maclaurin

Given the sum: $$ \sum_{i = 0}^n i^{1/5} $$

How to find $A$ in:
$$ \sum_{i = 0}^n i^{1/5} = A + O(\frac1{n^6}) $$
I tried to use Euler–Maclaurin formula and obtained numbers that confused me?

Comment: Your title says $i^{1/8}$. Which one do you need?

Comment: Approximate by an integral of $x^{1/5}$.

Comment: Show us how you used Euler-Maclaurin, maybe we'll be able to see what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Mathematica:
$$
\sum_{j=1}^k j^{1/5}= \frac{5k^{6/5}}{6}+\frac{k^{1/5}}{2}-\frac{(\sqrt{5}-1)\Gamma(6/5)\zeta(6/5)}{\sqrt[5]{64\pi^6}}+\frac{1}{60}k^{-4/5}-\frac{1}{2500}k^{-14/5}+
$$
$$
+\frac{19}{187500}k^{-24/5}-\frac{551}{7812500}k^{-34/5}+\mathcal{O}\left(k^{-44/5}\right)
$$